# Как нарисовать соединяющую линию между двумя элементами? HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возникла проблема , у меня имеются 2 блока , которые с помощью Drag and Drop можно перемещать по странице.

Не могу придумать как реализовать прямую линию между ними, которая будет перерисовываться в зависимости от положения блоков.

Что лучше для этого использовать  svg или canvas?

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: "у меня имеются 2 блока , которые с помощью Drag and Drop можно перемещать по странице"© - а у меня нет, предлагаете мне написать то что уже  есть у вас !? __: /__ ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Два элемента

```js
const el1 = document.getElementById('el1')
const el2 = document.getElementById('el2')
const size = 50

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
let width = canvas.width = innerWidth
let height = canvas.height = innerHeight

/*------------------------------------*/

let current = null
const elements = {
  el1: {
    x: Math.random() * (width - size),
    y: Math.random() * (height - size),
    startX: 0,
    startY: 0
  },

  el2: {
    x: Math.random() * (width - size),
    y: Math.random() * (height - size),
    startX: 0,
    startY: 0
  }
}

// начальное положение
translate(el1, elements.el1.x, elements.el1.y)
translate(el2, elements.el2.x, elements.el2.y)
drawLine(
  elements.el1.x,
  elements.el2.x,
  elements.el1.y,
  elements.el2.y
)

/*------------------------------------*/

el1.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown)
el2.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown)


function onMouseDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // координаты нажатия мыши внутри элемента
  elements[e.target.id].startX = e.x - elements[e.target.id].x
  elements[e.target.id].startY = e.y - elements[e.target.id].y

  current = e.target

  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp)
}

function onMouseMove(e) {
  const x = elements[current.id].x = e.x - elements[current.id].startX
  const y = elements[current.id].y = e.y - elements[current.id].startY

  translate(current, x, y)
  drawLine(
    elements.el1.x,
    elements.el2.x,
    elements.el1.y,
    elements.el2.y
  )
}

function onMouseUp() {
  document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
  document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp)
}

/*------------------------------------*/

function translate(el, x, y) {
  el.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
}

function drawLine(x1, x2, y1, y2) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
  context.beginPath()
  // из центра квадрата
  context.moveTo(x1 + size / 2, y1 + size / 2)
  // в центр другого квадрата
  context.lineTo(x2 + size / 2, y2 + size / 2)
  context.stroke()
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: tomato;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="el1"></div>
<div id="el2"></div>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Много элементов

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
let width = canvas.width = innerWidth
let height = canvas.height = innerHeight

/*------------------------------------*/

const elements = {}
const num = 7
const size = 50
let current = null

for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  // создание dom-элемента
  const element = document.createElement('div')
  element.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown)
  const id = 'el' + i
  element.id = id
  document.body.prepend(element)

  // тут будут храниться и изменяться все его координаты
  elements[id] = {
    x: Math.random() * (width - size),
    y: Math.random() * (height - size),
    startX: 0,
    startY: 0
  }

  // начальное положение
  translate(element, elements[id].x, elements[id].y)
}

// соединяем линиями
connect(elements)

/*------------------------------------*/

function onMouseDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // координаты нажатия мыши внутри элемента
  elements[e.target.id].startX = e.x - elements[e.target.id].x
  elements[e.target.id].startY = e.y - elements[e.target.id].y

  current = e.target

  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp)
}

function onMouseMove(e) {
  const x = elements[current.id].x = e.x - elements[current.id].startX
  const y = elements[current.id].y = e.y - elements[current.id].startY

  translate(current, x, y)
  connect(elements)
}

function onMouseUp() {
  document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
  document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp)
}

/*------------------------------------*/

function translate(el, x, y) {
  el.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
}

function connect(elements) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)

  for (let i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
    drawLine(
      elements['el' + i].x,
      elements['el' + (i + 1)].x,
      elements['el' + i].y,
      elements['el' + (i + 1)].y
    )
  }
}

function drawLine(x1, x2, y1, y2) {
  context.beginPath()
  // из центра квадрата
  context.moveTo(x1 + size / 2, y1 + size / 2)
  // в центр другого квадрата
  context.lineTo(x2 + size / 2, y2 + size / 2)
  context.stroke()
}

/*------------------------------------*/

onresize = () => {
  width = canvas.width = innerWidth
  height = canvas.height = innerHeight
  connect(elements)
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: А как можно соединить таким способом несколько блоков?

Comment: @OnlyWeb положить `drawLine` в цикл

Answer (score 5):

Когда я делал [приложение для визуализации графов](https://graphionic-4c2eb.web.app/), я столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Сначала, я посмотрел на уже существующие решения похожих по функционалу продуктов.

1. [Вот в этом приложении для визуализации схем баз данных](https://app.dbdesigner.net/designer/schema/guest_template), которое использует для отрисовки линий canvas, при изменении хотя бы одной линии перерисовывается весь холст, поскольку canvas не очень подходит для таких вещей.
2. [А вот в этом](https://dbdiagram.io/d) для отрисовки линий используется svg и мы можем наблюдать плавное изменение линий при перемещении элементов. Поэтому я рекомендовал бы вам использовать именно svg (хотя зависит конечно от вашего приложения).

Общий алгоритм создания линий с помощью svg такой:

1. При создании приложения (или той его части, где будут отрисовываться лини) создаем на заднем фоне svg-контейнер.

```js
const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

// Это просто пример родительского элемента
const parent = document.body;

parent.append(svg);
```

2. Для создание линии между двумя точками нужно создать svg-элемент отвечающий за это и добавить его в svg-контейнер

```js
// Создает прямую линию. Думаю также подойдут полилиния или кривые Безье
const line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');

// Установит точки конца и начала на 0 относительно svg-контейнера в котором будет находится линия
// Если это не линия, а полилиния и кривая, то нужно будет устанавливать атрибуты соответствующие типу элементу. Подробнее здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82
line.setAttribute('x1', 0);
line.setAttribute('y1', 0);
line.setAttribute('x2', 0);
line.setAttribute('y2', 0);

svgContainer.append(line);
```

3. Каждый раз при обновлении координат точек, к которым привязана линия устанавливать новые значения для атрибутов линии с помощью метода DOM-элементов setAttribute. Думаю для наблюдения за изменениями в элементах подойдет [MutationObserver](https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer), но я реализовывал это с помощью [собственных событий](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event). В любом случае решать вам.

Удачи

Comment: Интересное у Вас приложение)

Comment: const parent = document.body;  избегайте создания указателей на объекты уже имеющие указатель подобная практика может привести к утечке памяти

Comment: что делает нерабочий пример в сниппетах !?

Comment: Я просто показал, как это примерно делать. Это и не задумывалось как рабочий пример