# Как правильно нарисовать линию от одного элемента к другому

Tags: javascript, canvas

Не могу никак разобраться с задачей рисования линии от одного элемента до другого:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), 
one = document.getElementById('one'),
two = document.getElementById('two');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(one.getBoundingClientRect().left, two.getBoundingClientRect().left);
ctx.lineTo(one.getBoundingClientRect().top, two.getBoundingClientRect().top);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
#one, #two{width:10px;height:10px;position:absolute;background:#000;}
#one{top:40px;}
#two{left:50px;top:10px;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<span id="one"></span>
<span id="two"></span>
```

То есть по факту, нужно четко рисовать от одно центра элемента к другому, чтобы линия не разрывалась, но я не могу никак врубиться как мне эти точки найти и расстояние, точек может быть много и нужно, чтобы они от одной начинали двигаться и до последней одной линией.

Как можно так написать цикл, чтобы точек могло быть много.
Выручайте народ, никак не могу врубиться.

Comment: правильнее будет на canvas'e рисовать эти квадраты, а не в html

Comment: и также использовать `SVG` в `canvas` можно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1069033/331312

Comment: `ctx.moveTo(one.left + one.width/2, one.top + one.height/2);

ctx.lineTo(two.left + two.width/2, two.top + two.height/2);`

Comment: @ᅠhᅠ, не работает. Можете полный пример как я написал, сделать?

Comment: https://github.com/Verhov/arrows_for_blocks

Comment: @MaximLensky, можешь пример сделать без использования сторнних либ? Мой код поправить?

Comment: нее - это геморрой - проще подключил и всё работает из коробки https://ibb.co/6wmnF4N  вот с рабочего стола, а уговаривать или учиться когда надо дать готовый продукт нету времени - сделал срубил бабло и аля улю

Comment: @MaximLensky ну вообще это очень легко

Comment: @h я не спорю но это когда умеешь а когда нет то это ужас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как это сделать? Очень просто:

```js
// инструменты для рисования 
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// устанавливаем размеры равные ширине и высоте окна
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

// получаем размеры и координаты блоков
const one_rect = one.getBoundingClientRect()
const two_rect = two.getBoundingClientRect()

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(
    // от цента квадрата
    one_rect.left + one_rect.width/2,
    one_rect.top + one_rect.height/2,
)

ctx.lineTo(
  // к центру другого квадрата
    two_rect.left + two_rect.width/2,
    two_rect.top + two_rect.height/2,
)

ctx.stroke()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#one, #two{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
}

#one {
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
}

#two {
  left: 250px;
  top: 150px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<span id="one"></span>
<span id="two"></span>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но тут есть один не очевидный момент: в примере выше я у `body` убрал стандартный `margin`, который равен `8px`, что будет если его вернуть?

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// устанавливаем размеры равные ширине и высоте окна
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

// получаем размеры и координаты блоков
const one_rect = one.getBoundingClientRect()
const two_rect = two.getBoundingClientRect()

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(
    // от цента квадрата
    one_rect.left + one_rect.width/2,
    one_rect.top + one_rect.height/2,
)

ctx.lineTo(
  // к центру другого квадрата
    two_rect.left + two_rect.width/2,
    two_rect.top + two_rect.height/2,
)

ctx.stroke()
```

```css
#one, #two{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
}

#one {
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
}

#two {
  left: 250px;
  top: 150px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<span id="one"></span>
<span id="two"></span>
```

Мы всё также с помощью `getBoundingClientRect` получаем размеры и координаты блоков, но написав `context.moveTo(x, y)` - мы передвигаемся к этой точке не от левого верхнего угла окна браузера, а от левого верхнего угла канваса. Чтобы решить эту проблему, можно от полученных координат просто вычесть `margin`.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// устанавливаем размеры равные ширине и высоте окна
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

// получаем размеры и координаты блоков
const one_rect = one.getBoundingClientRect()
const two_rect = two.getBoundingClientRect()

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(
    // от цента квадрата
    one_rect.left + one_rect.width/2 - 8, // <--
    one_rect.top + one_rect.height/2 - 8, // <--
)

ctx.lineTo(
  // к центру квадрата
    two_rect.left + two_rect.width/2 - 8, // <--
    two_rect.top + two_rect.height/2 - 8, // <--
)

ctx.stroke()
```

```css
#one, #two{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
}

#one {
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
}

#two {
  left: 250px;
  top: 150px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<span id="one"></span>
<span id="two"></span>
```

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1124144/355286

Comment: Отлично! Все работает! Кстати если сможешь добавить цикл по точкам, через цикл, будет зачетно, для поддержания вопроса =)

Comment: @FixiDens я скинул ссылку. Там есть функции `connect` и `drawline` которые делают то, что тебе нужно.